Ruff pandas-use-of-dot-at (PD008) - convert to numpy array for performance
The ruff linting code pandas-use-of-dot-at (PD008) states:

If performance is an important consideration, convert the object to a NumPy array, which will provide a much greater performance boost than using .at over .loc.

What does this mean, and why is it faster?  How can I apply it to their example of selecting "Maria" from students_df?
import pandas as pd

students_df = pd.read_csv("students.csv")
students_df.at["Maria"]


Also, preempting close votes, I'm not simply asking how to convert a pandas dataframe to a numpy array. Hoping that people coming here for this ruff linting code can find a meaningful response as to why they might consider using the numpy array approach and have a matching example of how to do it.


How can I apply it to their example of selecting "Maria" from
students_df?

pd.read_csv("students.csv").at["Maria"] doesn't make sense. It will definitely trigger a TypeError because .at[] uses DataFrame._get_value(index, col, takeable: 'bool' = False) under the hood and this one requires two arguments. Even with a valid call, switching to numpy doesn't makes sense either in this context since it doesn't support label-indexing.
Ruff taps pandas-vet to lint the pandas code and quoting the owner in pandas-vet/issues/105 :

The founding idea behind pandas-vet is to make pandas a little bit more approachable, especially for those who are still learning. As a result, we definitely realize that our opinions aren't the best choice for everyone in all instances.

About using numpy (in general) for faster code, it ain't an absolute truth IMO. Not totally sure what they mean TBH, but it depends anyway on many factors: context, data, your machine..
